# Integrar Spark utilizando maven

Tags: jsf, primefaces, maven

Olá.

Eu comprei o theme+layout spark do primefaces.

Na comunidade me escreveram que para usar o layout. Eu teria que importar o arquivo  `spark-theme.1.0.war`. Assim que importar, apareceria o conjunto completo do primeface spark.

Fiz exatamente o que foi dito, porém me indicaram copiar as pastas `sources` e `source` para `META-INF` e pôr no `pom.xml` essa instrução:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>internal.org.primefaces.theme</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

e atualizar o projeto. Feito isso era para aparecer o layout, porém não deu certo.

Mais uma vez pedi auxílio à equipe e me indicaram o maven build.

Ao ir na opção Build Maven e pôr em Gol  essa instrução:

```
install:install-file -Dfile=D:\spark-1.0-theme.jar -DgroupId=org.primefaces.theme -DartifactId=spark -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DlocalRepositoryPath= C:\Users\root\.m2\repository\internal -DgeneratePom=true
```

E executar o run e voltar no `pom.xml` e pôr novamente o:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>internal.org.primefaces.theme</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Que iria me retornar o layout spark.

Bem não faz muito tempo que uso o maven e ao fazer isso tudo, ao baixar ele me retorna ERROR. Uma falha ao tentar realizar esse procedimento.

Poderiam me auxiliar para poder continuar meu projeto da faculdade?

Comment: Você tem o `spark-1.0-theme.jar` em `D:` mesmo, certo? Ele é tudo que você precisa? Qual o erro que é informado, que você citou, mas não colocou na questão?

Answer (score 1):

Falta adicionar no seu `pom.xml` ou no `settings.xml` do `.m2` que seu `.m2` também é um repositório.

Mas a melhor coisa a se fazer, levando em consideração que sua aplicação pode ser instalada em uma maquina que não seja a que você vai fazer o procedimento, é criar um repositório remoto para as bibliotecas adquiridas manualmente.

https://emarineli.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/repositorio-maven-com-nexus-em-5-minutos/

Comment: Giceu, podes juntar informação desse link aqui na resposta? dessa maneira se o link se perder um dia a resposta mantém o conteúdo.