# Como integrar Theme Spark - primefaces com Maven

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Alguém pode me ajudar com o meu problema? Estou tentando integrar o Theme Spark com o maven para subir o tema. Entretanto, estou com muitas dificuldades.

http://www.primefaces.org/spark/

Olhei na documentação e não tem nenhuma instrução ensinando como realizar o procedimento de instalação do theme.

obrigado

Comment: Qual problema? Quais dificuldades? Veja se isto ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58450/integrar-spark-utilizando-maven

Answer (score 1):

Por ser um tema Premium ele não estará aberto ao publico, a menos que você pague.

Provavelmente quando você comprar eles te passam as instruções para usá-lo ou você pode entrar em contato com o suporte deles.

Answer (score 1):

boa tarde.

Eu resolvi o meu problema da seguinte maneira:

Os arquivos que vem no theme premium são:

```
1. .Jar 
2. A pasta resources com o CSS, Images, Fonts e JS.
```

Para realizar a integração via Maven é necessário:

1. Baixar o Maven manualmente e configurar ná máquina.
2. Via cmd eu naveguei até a pasta que estava salvo o theme, ou seja, o .jar
3. Depois de ter instalado e configurado o maven eu executei o seguinte comando via cmd:

   **`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=spark-theme-1.0.jar -DgroupId=org.primefaces.themes -DartifactId=spark -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`**

E depois executei essa dependência no pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Funcionou que só uma beleza! Espero ajudar outras pessoas.